# Angular CLI suddenly fails on serve and build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am working on this angular CLI project and all of a sudden it started to fail on serve/build with the following error:

```
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/terry/git/ngsprj/src/styles.css' in '/Users/terry/git/ngspr'
 @ multi ./src/styles.css
```

**I am using:
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.32.3
node: 7.2.0**

I even tried creating a styles.css file but it still fails.

Has something changed?

Answer (score 0):

Paths in `angular-cli.json` are relative to the project root (`src`/ normally). For instance, you have the `src/styles.css` file, but in `angular-cli.json` it's listed only as styles.css.

Comment: The file did not exist which is why I created it temporarily. I do not know why ng was looking for this file. (I only have scss files) I had to re-create a new project and paste my components over and now it works. I really don't understand what happened there and where does it  need this file.